# When I try to install package pyo on Mac m2 the terminal print this how can I fix this?

Tags: python-3.x, pyo

gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DUSE_PORTAUDIO -DUSE_PORTMIDI -DUSE_OSC -Iinclude -I/usr/local/Cellar/liblo/0.31/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libsndfile/1.2.0/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/portmidi/2.0.4/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c src/engine/pyomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/engine/pyomodule.o -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-strict-aliasing -O3 -g0 -DNDEBUG
src/engine/pyomodule.c:25:10: fatal error: 'sndfile.h' file not found
#include "sndfile.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyo
Running setup.py clean for pyo
Failed to build pyo
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I don't know what to do